# Snowflake Information Schema behavior for View tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake. I am creating a view in snowflake as below

```
create view TABLENAME_VIEW as select * from test.stage.TABLENAME;
```

while running a select statement on information_schema.tables, I am getting the row_count of view table as null whereas doing select count(*) on the view tables gives the count.

Can someone please help on this.

| TABLE_NAME | ROW_COUNT | TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TABLENAME | 5 | TEST | BASE TABLE |
| TABLENAME_VIEW | NULL | TEST | VIEW |

```
select count(*) from TABLENAME_VIEW;
```

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are not tables (unless it an materializes view). So they have no rows. When you select from the view it becomes a projection of the underlying table/s

This can be seen by creating another view that has a “WHERE false” thus will return 0 to you select count(*) from the will return 0, but it will have no row. OR if your view had “limit 1”. It will have a count of 1, but which one is the magic part.

Comment: Thanks Simeon for clarifying it.

 I have another part in this question. I am doing POC on cross account data share and making cross schema access for views.  In the parent account i could see data in the main table view, whereas in the customer account the count is 0. Share for similar schema is working fine. Does it have to be main table for cross schema share as well?

Comment: SHARES cannot span Databases, but off the top of my I don't recall if they can span a schema also. But if they where "bad" then you shouldn't be able to share it.